# How can I print special HTML characters correctly, using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to print a string, like this:

> Noticias de Fútbol.

But when I print this string, it displays like this:

> Noticias de F�tbol.

I tried `htmlspecialchar()` and many more, but my output remains the same.

```
$str = "Noticias de Fútbol";
$strfoot = html_entity_decode($str);
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use charset `utf 8`  and `htmlentities` function of php

Like

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

$test=htmlentities("Sisälämpötila");

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `html_entity_decode`, you can just simply print out your `$str` with `echo`, but you have to make sure your html has this line of code in the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: I already added that but still it show me like this kind of o/p

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely outputting to a page that has the wrong charset specified. To confirm this open a JavaScript console and evaluate `window.document.charSet` and `window.document.characterSet`.

If that is the case you can use a meta tag to inform the browser of your intended charset:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I'm reading elsewhere the tag might be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php file is not utf-8 but the browser is reading it as utf-8 which is giving you that question mark character. Save your file as utf-8, most editors/ides have options to set the charset of the file.